# Do system component effects stack?

Tags: tales-of-honor-sf

In the game Tales of Honor: Secret Fleet (I assume both iOS and Android version are the same), do effects from system components stack?

As an example, you can have a component for your lasers which shortens their reload time. The component itself displays the reload as a number less than 1, e.g. 0.950, with each upgrade lessening the number further.

If I deploy another component with the same effect, the number on both components seems to be tied only to the upgrade level of the respective component, 0.950 on one and 0.920 on a more upgraded one.

Question is, do these effects stack, perhaps by using each of them as a factor for calculating the real reload speed, or does the game just take the best one and use that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for this answer myself and couldn't find it, so I just did a quick test:

I had a weapon loader at .87, .92, and .97 weapon speed. I tested with a stopwatch and averaged around 9 and 41 seconds without any weapon loader upgrade. Then I tried the .87 only and averaged around 8 and 23 seconds. Then I tested all of them together and averaged at 7 and 34 seconds.

When I did some math with those numbers, it appears that the game takes the non-upgraded time and then applies your best upgrade and gives you a new time. After that, it uses that new time with your second best upgrade and then uses that third time for your third best upgrade. Which is still nice but not as good as if all three just got added together which would give you a missile refresh time of 7 and 15 seconds as opposed to the 7 and 34 which it ends up being.